# Store relationships between objects (n:m), display them and change the way they are displayed interactively

Tags: visualization, data-visualization, interactive

I have the following problem. I want to relaunch a tool that displays the relationship between multiple objects. In this case there are numerous works of art, each is more or less related to all the others. In its inital state the display shows all objects (represented by a thumbnail and/or title) in different clouds depending on the main category each object belongs to (think sculpture, painting, poem etc.). When a user clicks on an object, all objects are rearranged: the clicked object is displayed in the center, all other objects arre arrange arround it. The closeer they are to center, the closer they are related (depending on additional parameters).

The current version of the tool can be seen here: http://atlas.taswir.org/

The relauch is necessary due to several issues: currently it's flash based, it is a very clunky solution pieced together by several long gone devs, to add new items the XML file of doom has to be hand-edited etc.

Which (finally :) brings me to a question: I'm sure that this is not a unique problem. Are there any tools, frameworks, classes... anything that can be used as a starting point to get a better result? I'm not sure what to look for. HTML5/PHP would be ideal, but I'll take nearly anything.

Answer (score 0):

Check out d3 [Force Layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout). It can give you the layout and interactivity you are looking for.